# Compiling a .jar file on a Mac, even with the CLASSPATH option, keeps telling me the package does not exist

Tags: java, jar

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using the (probably outdated) [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/doc/) library.  I downloaded it from its [Github page](https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse) and generated the /src/ folder into a jar using the command `jar cf prefuse-2007-10-21.jar src`.  I have the .jar file and a test program in the same directory.  When I am in that directory, I try to compile my program using `javac *.java -classpath prefuse-2007-10-21.jar`.  Rearranging command line arguments resulted in the same errors.  A similar program I wrote about a week ago compiled with its own .jar with a similar command.

My program's import statements are as follows:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;

    import prefuse.data.*;
    import prefuse.util.*;
    import prefuse.io.*;
```

I am using Mac OS X Yosemite and have Java 8 installed.

Comment: Consider posting the actual error message.  Also, you put the source in a jar?  Try compiling it and packing the resulting .class files into a jar.

Comment: I got "error: package prefuse.data does not exist".  And I need to have the two as separate files because this is for a project and my TA needs to be able to view and compile the source code.  @JeffreyBosboom

Comment: Ah, shouldn't you compile the `.java` files BEFORE you try and jar them?  A Jar file is a package of resources and classes (wrapped in a zip file)...

Comment: I need to use external classes from prefuse-2007-10-21.jar in the program I'm writing.  So I can't compile the program I'm writing without including that .jar in the classpath.  It's just that including it in the classpath isn't working.